# Estimation of $\mathrm{ARMAX}(1,1,2)$ using panel data

Tags: regression, estimation, econometrics, stata, armax

I'm have an application that after some manipulation boils down to an $\mathrm{ARMAX}(1,1,2)$ with some parametric restrictions:

$$y_{i,g,t}= k + \beta y_{i,g,t-1} + \epsilon_{i,t}+\beta_e \epsilon_{i,t-1}+\sum_{s=1}^2(\eta_{x,s}x_{i,t+1-s}+\eta_{\bar{x},s}\bar{x}_{i,t-s}+\eta_{z,s}z_{i,t+1-s}) \tag{1} \label{1}$$
with parametric restrictions

$\beta_e=-\beta$

$\eta_{\bar{x},1}=-\eta_{x,2}=\beta\eta_{x,1}$

$\eta_{\bar{x},2}=\eta_{z,2}=0$

and $\epsilon_{i,t}\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, and for all $s,\,t$, $\mathrm{cov}(\epsilon_{i,t},\epsilon_{i,t-s})=0$. Also, $-1<\beta<1$ is assumed.

**The problem:** I have panel data and don't know how to estimate \eqref{1} (or implement it in, say, Stata for instance).

**Background:** motivation and what I have tried. The original setting is a dynamic linear model with social interactions as follows:

$$y_{i,g,t}= k + c x_{i,t} + d z_{g,t} + \beta m_{g,t-1} + \epsilon_{i,t} \tag{2} \label{2}$$
with $\epsilon_{i,t}\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and for all $s,\,t$, $\mathrm{cov}(\epsilon_{i,t},\epsilon_{i,t-s})=0$. Also, $-1<\beta<1$ is assumed.

where $y_{i,g,t}$ corresponds to an individual $i$ action (member of group $g$) in time $t$. It depends of individual-specific characteristics $x_{i,t}$, group-specific characteristics $z_{g,t}$, and the average choice in that group in the previous period $m_{g,t-1}$.

[Brock and Durlauf (2001)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1573441201050073) show that the model is identified (i.e. there is no [reflection problem](https://academic.oup.com/restud/article-abstract/60/3/531/1570385)): taking expectations and using the lag operator $\mathrm{L}$:

$$m_{g,t}= k + c \bar{x}_{g,t} + d z_{g,t} + \beta \mathrm{L} m_{g,t} $$
$$\Rightarrow m_{g,t}=\dfrac{ k + c \bar{x}_{g,t} + d z_{g,t} }{1-\beta \mathrm{L}}$$

So, model \eqref{2} can be rewritten as:

$$y_{i,g,t}= \dfrac{k}{1-\beta} + c x_{i,t} + \sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\beta^{s}(c \bar{x}_{g,t-s} +\beta^{-1} d z_{g,t+1-s}) + \epsilon_{i,t} \tag{3}\label{3}$$

Thus, $y_{i,g,t}$ depends on the entire history $\{\bar{x}_{g,s},z_{g,s}\}_{s=0}^{t}$. The model is identified, because (i) $c$ is identified by the coefficients on $x_{i,t}$, (ii) then $\beta$ is identified by the ratio of coefficients on $\bar{x}_{g,t-1}$ and $\bar{x}_{g,t-2}$, (iii) then $k$ is identified by the constant and $d$ by the ratio of coefficients on $\bar{z}_{g,t}$ and $\bar{z}_{g,t-1}$.

Model \eqref{3} is reminiscent of the [Koyck (1954) model](https://repub.eur.nl/pub/1190) in its infinite part and parametric restriction (geometric progression in the coefficients). Subtracting $\beta y_{i,g,t-1}$ from \eqref{3} (Koyck transformation):

$$y_{i,g,t}= k +\beta y_{i,g,t-1} + c x_{i,t}-\beta c x_{i,t-1} + \beta c \bar{x}_{g,t-1} +d z_{g,t} + \epsilon_{i,t}-\beta\epsilon_{i,t-1} \tag{4}\label{4}$$
which can be cast as the general ARMAX(1,1,2) in \eqref{1} with the parametric restrictions I included.

Comment: it's not a matter of choosing lags because the expression you derived where you re-wrote it as an infinite sum is an EQUALITY. It's not a VAR. I can't go into estimation here and I don't know if it specifically solves your problem but I would have a look at andrew harvey's text.

Comment: He may not include an exact example like yours but he has a lot of good ones. https://www.amazon.com/Econometric-Analysis-Time-Economics-Handbooks/dp/026208189X/ref=sr_1_1?crid=ZAIPB8PE7AF3&keywords=andrew+harvey+time+series+analysis&qid=1680188517&sprefix=andrew+harvey+time+series+analysis%2Caps%2C157&sr=8-1

Comment: @mlofton indeed, not a VAR. To use a descriptive nomenclature, it's an $\mathrm{ARMAX}(0,0,+\infty)$. The $+\infty$ is theoretically there; not akin to choosing $p,q$ in an $\mathrm{ARMA}(p,q)$. However, the parametric restrictions imply that contributions of lags go to zero as $t-s$ approach $-\infty$. So, heuristically, I had hopes of starting with 2 lags and keep including more lags while either $\beta^{s}c$ or $\beta^{s-1}d$ is significant. I'll add this point to the question, so it becomes clearer.

Comment: $(2)$ does not seem to be either ARMAX or ARDL, because it contains neither moving average nor autoregressive terms. Or if it does, this is not obvious from the representation that you are using.

Comment: Ararat: Hi. I'[m not clear on how the re-writing of it helps ? Can't one think of the $z$ and the $x$ as exogenous variables and then view it as a  ARDL ?

Comment: @RichardHardy Rewritten it to have a more explicit representation.

Comment: @mlofton Indeed, I agree with you that it doesn't. Trying to reach a representation that is suitable for estimation, I eventually reached an explicit ARMAX(1,1,2). Haven't solved it yet because I don't know how to estimate it using panel data.

Comment: @Ararat, I do not think $(4)$ is helpful, because it introduces the same lag polynomial on both sides of the equation, so in the end it just cancels out. It does not make the process ARMAX(1,1,x), only makes it look like one. The ACF of the process does not change when we change the representation, and the ACF is key for determining what process we have. So we seem to have just a good old multiple regression model, unless you could show us it has some AR, MA or distributed lag component where the lag polynomials on the left and the right do not cancel out.